# 403 Forbidden in Google Chrome (only) when I call twitter search with Jquery (ajax)

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I have this issue with Google Chrome (v26.0.1410.64m).
When i call Twitter search with jquery, i get the following error:

```
GET https://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=youtube&rpp=5&result_type=recent&callback=jQuery19101530768966767937_1365645647773&_=1365645647774 403 (Forbidden)
```

This is the code i used :

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "https://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=youtube&rpp=5&result_type=recent",
   contentType: "application/json",
   dataType: "jsonp",
   success: function(data) {
       console.log(data);
   }
});
```

On Firefox, Internet Explorer, Safari and Opera this is working. But in Chrome i have this forbidden error. I try to add in my .htaccess the following code for the cross-origin :

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

Nothing has changed. Where i'm wrong?
If this help, I'm working in dev environment with virtual domain (en.domain.com.local, fr.domain.com.local, etc...) on Windows/Apache.

Thank you for your help. Sorry for my English.

Comment: Works in Chrome, at least in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PpMKk/).

Comment: indeed.. So this is my Apache configuration?

Comment: Your Apache and .htaccess configuration should have nothing to do with this, assuming you are calling this from HTML code.

Comment: Ok it's weird. Where i'm wrong? You need more information about something? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

All right I founded what's wrong.
When i've replace *https* to **http**, Google Chrome has accepted the query. I guess it was a security issue. For now, my website is not working with https protocol. Thanks !

**EDIT :** Hum... false positive. It's worked once. But when i refresh the page, the forbidden error has return.

**EDIT 2 :** Wow... In fact, the script worked fine when the developper console of Google Chrome is closed... I have the same result with the fiddle made by [Perception](https://stackoverflow.com/users/680925/perception)

Comment: when you refreshed the page, was it still https link to twitter?

Comment: Yes, but when I use the "force cache refresh" mode of Google Chrome, the forbidden is still here, http or https.

Comment: This has to do with Google Chrome user profiles. I have the exact same issue: getting 403 from twitter ONLY when dev tools open in Google Chrome for one specific Google chrome user profile (top right icon), but works when switched to another.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently ran into this problem, but I was able to find a hack/workaround.

What I found to work was introducing an arbitrary timeout of about 100ms. I used 150ms just to be really sure that the hack will work.

```
function latestTweet(screenName) {
  var deferred = new $.Deferred();

  // Introduce a timeout before we make a search request to Twitter.
  // This is added in the event that this function is called when
  // the page is ready and your user is using Chrome. When in Chrome
  // and a search request is sent to Twitter it will always return a 403.
  setTimeout(function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: "//search.twitter.com/search.json?q=from%3A"+screenName,
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: function(data) {
        if (data && data.results) {
          data = data.results;
          if (typeof data.length === 'number') {
            deferred.resolve(data[0]);
          } else {
            deferred.reject();
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }, 150); // This works with 100ms, but pad just to be sure.

  return deferred.promise();
}

// Somewhere in my code ...
latestTweet('someScreenName').done(displayTweet);
```

Now in Chrome you shouldn't get a 403 Forbidden response and in all other browsers it will continue to work.